# How do I overlay JavaScript onto a static image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am re-designing a website for a major University, and they use java images on most of their pages.

How do I place/inlay a JavaScript slide show onto a static image (ie: background image).

(I know it is a weird combination of JavaScript, CSS, and XHTML.)

Comment: I think you mean "Javascript", not "Java" - the two are completely different.

Comment: this slideshow is in Javascript or Java???

Comment: Java is to Javascript what Car is to Carpet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: Well that confusion aside, the question is still extremely vague. What does the page look like? What slide show package? etc etc.

Comment: Java and Javascript are languages. Car is a vehicle. Carpet is not a vehicle. Maybe a motorcycle/car comparison for the confused readers would be better... :P

Comment: its javascript, and i am putting a slide show "inside" of a static image.  The package is just simple jpg images.  If that answers the questions.

Answer (score 0):

if it is javascript:

I would use CSS and div tags. Background is a static image as defined in CSS and then between the div tags add the javascript. That's the easiest way. If you wanted to avoid div tags you could add it as a single cell table with the background image as the static and again the javascript added in-between etc etc.

If it's java then I'm sorry but I have no experience with java... and to everyone else saying that it's probs be javascript not java I have this to say... it's an academic website.. you never know... v_v"

Jon